# SQL Server : stored procedure many-to-many table query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, many-to-many

I have 3 tables `Campaign`, `Mall`, `MallCampaign` (many-to-many) and want to order nearest campaigns which are  available in one or more malls.

In the first query; I am eligible for reaching the campaigns' distance which are available in different malls. But need to do it for all campaigns not only one (Id=79). I couldn't manage to do it with JOIN.

```
SELECT 
   m.MallId, 
   ROUND(@geo1.STDistance(geography::Point(m.MallLatitude, m.MallLongitude, 4326))/1000,1) AS Distance
FROM 
   MallCampaign mc
INNER JOIN 
   Mall m ON m.MallId = mc.MallId
WHERE 
   m.IsActive != 0 AND mc.CampaignId = 79
ORDER BY 
   Distance

SELECT 
    ca.CampaignId, ca.CampaignTitle
FROM 
    Campaign ca
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want?  It sorts by campaign id first and then by distance:

```
SELECT mc.CampaignId, m.MallId,
       ROUND(@geo1.STDistance(geography::Point(m.MallLatitude, m.MallLongitude, 4326))/1000,1) AS Distance
FROM MallCampaign mc join
     Mall m
     ON m.MallId = mc.MallId
WHERE m.IsActive <> 0
ORDER BY mc.CampaignId, Distance;
```

EDIT:

Your original question didn't have a `top` in it, which I sort of expected.  To handle this, you want to use `row_number()`.  In this case, it is easiest to do two subqueries (or CTEs):

```
select CampaignId, MallId, Distance
from (select mc.*,
             row_number() over (partition by CampaignId order by distance) as seqnum
      from (SELECT mc.CampaignId, m.MallId,
                   ROUND(@geo1.STDistance(geography::Point(m.MallLatitude, m.MallLongitude, 4326))/1000,1) AS Distance
            FROM MallCampaign mc join
                 Mall m
                 ON m.MallId = mc.MallId
            WHERE m.IsActive <> 0
           ) mc
     ) mc
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: What if only I want to show 1 row(smallest distance row) of one campaign? I tried MIN(Distance) but it gives error for GROUP BY section for the other selected items.

Comment: Yes, I have missed it sorry. Also added join for campaign details and ordered by distance. Works fine :) Thanks a lot!